# Replace multiple column values based on the logical set of the same dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. I want to replace any column values where `df[c("PhysicalActivity_yn_agesurvey", "smoker_former_or_never_yn_agesurvey", "NOT_RiskyHeavyDrink_yn_agesurvey",  "Not_obese_yn_agesurvey", "HEALTHY_Diet_yn_agesurvey")] != df$SURVEY_MIN]` is `true` with NA. How do I do that in R?

```
df <- structure(list(PhysicalActivity_yn_agesurvey = c(58, 47, 47, 
50, 53, 59), smoker_former_or_never_yn_agesurvey = c(58, 47, 
47, 50, 53, 59), NOT_RiskyHeavyDrink_yn_agesurvey = c(59, 48, 
47, 50, 53, 59), Not_obese_yn_agesurvey = c(58, 47, 47, 50, 53, 
59), HEALTHY_Diet_yn_agesurvey = c(58, 47, 47, 50, 53, 59), SURVEY_MIN = c(58, 
47, 47, 50, 53, 59)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

These are the codes I tried:

```
df[lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x != df$SURVEY_MIN, TRUE, FALSE))] <- NA
```

Also tried:

```
df[c("PhysicalActivity_yn_agesurvey", "smoker_former_or_never_yn_agesurvey", "NOT_RiskyHeavyDrink_yn_agesurvey",
                "Not_obese_yn_agesurvey", "HEALTHY_Diet_yn_agesurvey")] [df[c("PhysicalActivity_yn_agesurvey", "smoker_former_or_never_yn_agesurvey", "NOT_RiskyHeavyDrink_yn_agesurvey",
                 "Not_obese_yn_agesurvey", "HEALTHY_Diet_yn_agesurvey")] != df$SURVEY_MIN] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing for loops is very bad practise in R ! (99% of the time)

```
df[(df != df$SURVEY_MIN)]<-NA
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand your question correctly, but this should do the trick:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:(ncol(df)-1)) { 
    if (df[i,j] != df$SURVEY_MIN[i]) {
      df[i,j] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```